# Problem with Verilog Dataflow testbench causing different errors on different sites

Tags: verilog, dataflow

This program is in Dataflow Verilog.  What I'm trying to do is make an adder and subtractor dependent on a selector.  I am currently getting some errors that are either "syntax error in continuous assignment" for line 10, (the assign {cout...},) or "Error launching EPWave: [Could not parse file: $timescale not found in the header.]. Could not load './dataflow_hw_1.vcd'".

I have looked all over the internet in search of how to solve this problem, but I keep attempting the recommended solutions to no avail.  I don't know what's wrong when trying to testbench it.

Here is the code:

```
module dataflow_1 (a[7:0],b[7:0],out[7:0],cout);

  input a,b;
  output out,cout;
  //if a have odd number of 1s, output = a + b
  //else if even positions have even number of 1s in total, output = a-b

  assign selectorOdd = (a[1]^ a[3]^ a[5] ^ a[7]);
  assign selectorEven = (~selectorOdd & ~(a[0] ^ a[2] ^ a[4] ^ a[6])); 
  assign {cout,out[7:0]} = (selectorOdd & ({a[7:0] + b[7:0}) | (selectorEven & ({a[7:0] - b[7:0]}));


endmodule
```

Here is the testbench code:

```
// Code your testbench here
module dataflow_1();

  reg [7:0] a;
  reg [7:0] b;
  wire [7:0] out;


   dataflow_1  test(
     .a(a),
     .b(b),
     .out(out)
  );

  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0, out);

    a = 8'b01010101;
    b = 8'b00000001;
  #100;

  end



endmodule
```

Comment: well, you do have a syntactic error there. Check for use of `[]` and `{}` in this statement.

Comment: If you're talking about line 10 missing a closing bracket on b[7:0] I've already tried that

Comment: and what happened?   btw, what is the meaning of braces `{}` there in the first place?

Comment: It didn't change anything, but you're right, they should be there.  The point of the curly braces {} are to concatenate the bits

Comment: I notice both modules are called `dataflow_1`. Whichever is compiled second will overwrite whichever is compiled first. In the case of EDA Playground, the design is compiled before the testbench.

Comment: @zebermeken in your case `{}` make no sense because there is just a single operand to the the concat, your expression. They are used, if you concatenate multiple arguments. In your case way braces only trash the view and make you easily miss the balance.

Comment: I'm a bit suprized no one has pointed out the port declarations is wrong. It should be `module dataflow_1 (input [7:0] a, input [7:0] b, output [7:0] out, output cout);` or you must code in 1995 coding style `module dataflow_1 (a, b, out, cout); input [7:0] a; input [7:0] b; output [7:0] out; output cout;`

Comment: I tried out all of your guys' solutions, but I'm still getting the same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
assign {cout,out[7:0]} = (selectorOdd & ({a[7:0] + b[7:0}) | (selectorEven & ({a[7:0] - b[7:0]}));
```

you used wrong `{}` and `[]`, `{}` used to concatenate the bits. It should be fixed like this:

```
assign {cout,out} = selectorOdd ? (a + b) : (selectorEven ? (a - b) : {9{1'b0}});
```

Your code should have more the case for else all. In this code if `selectorOdd` and `selectorEven` are `0`, I assign `{cout,out}={9{1'b0}}`.

Comment: I implemented your solution, but I still get errors of $timescale not found

Comment: Mysteriously the problem was solved by me rebooting my computer.  Thank you